# Extract midi files from Roland electronic drums

Tags: drums, midi

I was wondering whether it is possible to 'download' all the midi files (songs and especially kits (individual sounds)) of Roland V-drums.

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

sound?  highly doubtful.  You could try sampling it, but that is pretty painful.
You might find it at http://samples.kb6.de/downloads.php

midi - check your manual, otherwise see if it sends midi out that you can record with a pc midi sequencer to save to a midi file.

good luck to ya.